# Questions about the scalar function in joint limit distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, asymptotics

I wonder if I have such a condition, like I know the joint distirbution of:
(X, aY+b), where a and b are constant. Is it possible for me to calculate the joint distribution of (X,Y) based on (X, aY+b)? If yes, my idea is:

$(X,aY+b) \rightarrow N((\mu1,\mu2), \begin{pmatrix}\sigma_1^2 & \operatorname{cov}_{1,2}\\ \operatorname{cov}_{1,2} & \sigma_2^2\end{pmatrix})$
So the new variance of Y is Y/a^2, I only need to update my covariance matrix here I believe.

Is it correct? Thanks.

Comment: The covariances will scale by $\frac1a$ and the mean will change too

Comment: Yes, I address this problem by writing the joint distribution based on matrix form. Thanks a lot.